# Fill a matrix from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a Python beginner.

I'm encountering a problem during my loop to fill an absence matrix.

The absence matrix:

[image]

The index represents the date from the `beginning of 2020` to `today` and the columns represent the `USER IDs`.

The dataframe is as follows:

```
ID_USER  NOM      PRENOM      DATE_first         DATE_last
1        X        X           30/05/2020 00:00   01/06/2020 23:59
1        X        X           01/06/2020 00:00   02/06/2020 23:59
2        X        X           01/06/2020 00:00   03/06/2020 23:59
```

and the result I want:

```
DATE          user1    user2
29/05/2020    0        0
30/05/2020    1        0
01/06/2020    1        1
02/06/2020    1        1
03/06/2020    0        1
```

The objective is to fill the absence matrix with `1` and `0`.
`1` when the ID is absent between `DATE_DEBUT_ABSENCE` and `DATE_FIN_ABSENCE`.

Exemple :

- if in Dataframe `ID_USER=1` was absent between `2020/01/01` and `2020/01/05`:
- in the absence of matrice in `columns = 1`
- index : 2020/01/01 = 1
- 2020/01/02 = 1
- 2020/01/03 = 1
- 2020/01/04 = 1
- 2020/01/05 = 1

Here is the code I started  :

```py
for i in agenda.columns:
    for j  in absence_df.ID_USER:
        if i==j and  agenda.index[i]==absence_df.iloc[j,4]:
            agenda.index[i]==1
        else :
            print('false')
    j=j+1 
    i= i+1          
    break  
                    
    print(agenda)
```

Comment: As I said, it will depends of the way you created your first dataframe (your DATE_first and DATE_last fields). What you should be doing when asking a question about pandas is pasting the 'real' datas (a copy of a sample of a csv file or the code to create the dataframe). It would help a lot !

Comment: Thank's, DATE format is  datetime64[ns] and ID_USER is int64. it's my first day on the site so I don't know how to upload the files yet !

Comment: No trouble, I was just trying to help you for future questions ;-) Did you try my answer yet ? I think it will work with datetime64... The iteration of pandas' date_range will returns dates in this format I think.

Comment: We should continue this conversation in the "comments"' section of the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here your dates are in the datetime format, though I'm not sure this will work at first try (dates are tricky in python). It would be better if you could share a sample of the dataset, instead of just a snapchot...

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(2020,1,5)
daterange = pd.date_range(start, end)

users = sorted(list(set(df.ID_USER)))

agenda = pd.DataFrame(index=daterange, columns=users)
agenda.fillna(0, inplace=True)

for date in date_range:
  ix = df[
    (df.DATE_first < date) & (date < df.DATE_last)
  ].index
  users_absent = df.loc[ix, 'ID_USER'].tolist()
  agent.loc[date, users_absent] = 1
```

Comment: Just updated the field's names in regard to the question's update.

Comment: If this answers work, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: I didn't understand your following up question in the question's section last comment ? Is this a question about how date_range works ? I was just recreating a list of datetimes with all possible dates before start and end.